# How can I successfully build an Archiso image? ("airootfs is not a mountpoint")

Tags: arch-linux

Following https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Archiso, I try to build directly from a prestine template:

```
sudo cp -r /usr/share/archiso/configs/releng archlive
cd archlive
sudo ./build.sh -v -N foo
```

The result is:

```
[mkarchiso] INFO: Configuration settings
[mkarchiso] INFO:                   Command:   init
[mkarchiso] INFO:              Architecture:   x86_64
[mkarchiso] INFO:         Working directory:   work/x86_64
[mkarchiso] INFO:    Installation directory:   arch
[mkarchiso] INFO:        Pacman config file:   work/pacman.conf

[mkarchiso] INFO: Installing packages to 'work/x86_64/airootfs/'...
==> ERROR: work/x86_64/airootfs is not a mountpoint!
```

**ERROR: work/x86_64/airootfs is not a mountpoint!**

I tracked this down within the script to **line 63**:

```
mkarchiso ${verbose} -w "${work_dir}/x86_64" -C "${work_dir}/pacman.conf" -D "${install_dir}" init
```

... and executed the corresponding command manually:

```
sudo mkarchiso -v -w "work/x86_64" -C "work/pacman.conf" -D arch init
```

*This resulted in the same error.*

Any idea what may be causing it? It's been like this for a couple of months (i.e. several releases of the **archiso** package).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `archiso` project makes use of `pacstrap` from the `arch-install-scripts` project, which is ultimately where the message comes from.

This happens because recent versions of archiso, since commit https://git.archlinux.org/archiso.git/commit/?id=5f57352398e9ec7ab7bbe14fe24619987235060f, no longer execute `pacstrap -d`. However, this has been dropped from `pacstrap` for much longer, since commit https://git.archlinux.org/arch-install-scripts.git/commit/?id=0af6884aca68dcb7eed0b85fbc2960903df3d968 (which was released on 2018-01-27 as v18).

So, you are using an up-to-date version of `mkarchiso`, but an old version of `pacstrap`, even though `mkarchiso` assumes you are using the latest version of `pacstrap`.

The solution is to do a full system update. Alternatively, check to see if you have an old version of `pacstrap` in your `$PATH` which is overriding the version `mkarchiso` expects to see.

Comment: There was indeed an old version of 'pacstrap´ in my path. Apparently I had copied it back in Febuary.